# How to use python loop to generate sequence of titles for figures

Tags: python, string, loops, sequence

If I want to generate a sequence of strings `"layer 1", "layer 2", .... , "layer n"`, to use as the titles for my figures, is there an easy way to do this task by using a loop?

Thank you,

Comment: `seq_end_no =10 name_list= ["layer {}".format(i) for i in range(seq_end_no) ] print(name_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) or "f-strings" for short:

```py
def label_yielder(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        yield(f"label {i}")

# print them out
for x in label_yielder(5): 
    print(x)

# store them in a list
labels = [x for x  in label_yielder(5)]
```

Of course, if you're using a `for` loop for plotting already, you can use f-string directly in the plot call (I'll assume you're using `matplotlib.pyplot`, should hold for most of the other libraries as well):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randint

for x in range(5):
    data = randint(low=1,high=10, size=(10,))
    plt.plot(range(10), data, label=f"label{x+1}")
    plt.legend()
```